# How should two clients simultaneously wait for a value to be present in Redis?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

Redis provides *BRPOP* that allows a sender/receiver model with guaranteed delivery.

**Sender:** `LPUSH foo_key bar_value`
**Receiver:** `BRPOP foo_key ###`  => 'bar_value'

where *###* is an arbitrary expire interval, say 15 seconds.

However, what should you do if there are two receivers for the message?  I've thought about the following options:

1. *PUBLISH*/*SUBSCRIBE*, but this leads to a race condition if the sender *PUBLISH*es the message before the receiver *SUBSCRIBE*s to the channel.
2. The sender calls *SET+EXPIRE* on a key, and the receiver polls the key until a value is present, and then *GET*s the value.  The data eventually gets deleted based on the *EXPIRE* timeout.  I don't like this option because polling Redis might lead to poor performance if many clients are doing it at the same time, and also that the response is not real-time.

How do you set up a multiple-client receiver model with real-time, guaranteed delivery?

Only one message will ever be sent over a particular key in my schema, so there is no danger of a client accidentally receiving the same message twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I can use *BRPOPLPUSH* to achieve this.

**Sender:** `LPUSH foo_key bar_value` followed by `EXPIRE foo_key ###`
**Receivers:** `BRPOPLPUSH foo_key foo_key ###` => *bar_value*

where, as before, each *###* is some arbitrary expire interval, say 15 seconds.

Comment: I think you missed the name of the list that the receivers push to, I assume you meant the same `foo_key`. If that is the case, your receivers can end up processing the value multiple times if they finish their jobs before the timeout and return to `BRPOPLPUSH`ing.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post.  It should be `BRPOPLPUSH foo_key foo_key ###`

Comment: My point remains. Use different queues for different listeners, push to all/some/one as needed.

Comment: That would be a concern if multiple messages will be sent over the same key.  In my case, a key is unique to each message: the receiver gets a UUID, and as soon as it receives the data, it closes its connection.  I will explain that better in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The sender could push the value onto 2 queues, one queue for each receiver.

Each receiver could have the name of its queue in a configuration file. The receiver could use a blocking pop, thus no polling involved.

Of course, with this approach, if one of your receivers stops processing it will be easy to detect.

Comment: It may interest you to know that the author of Redis has created a new project to further explore the  'Redis as a job queue' use case: https://github.com/antirez/disque